# the set of all cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory

I want to prove the following theorem.

**Theorem.** There is no set $\Omega$ such that for every set $A$, there exists a $M\in\Omega$ with the same cardinality as $A$, that is: $|A|=|M|$.

In order to prove that, we suppose that there is such a set $\Omega$. By Cantors Theorem ([link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Cantor)) we know that $|\Omega|<|\mathfrak{P}(\Omega)|$. My question:

> how to show that $|\mathfrak{P}(\Omega)| \leq|\Omega|$? (This would lead to a contradiction and our theorem would be proved ;-D)

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to deduce $\lvert \mathfrak{P}(\Omega)\rvert \leq \lvert \Omega\rvert$ from the premises. But can you find/show the existence of a set that is at least as large as every member of $\Omega$?

Comment: No, there is no set that is at least as large as every member of $\Omega$

Comment: Well, since $\Omega$ would have to be a proper class, that is true, but under the assumption that $\Omega$ is a set, there is.

Comment: You mean $\bigcup\Omega$?

Comment: Looks promising. So if you look at that, can you find a contradiction?

Comment: That sounds very promising, yes. $\bigcup \Omega$ contains all ordinals — in fact, it **is** $\mathsf{Ord}$.

Comment: @BrianO Although the title seems to imply that, $\Omega$ doesn't need to be a class of ordinals.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf OK... You're in ZFC, nevertheless? Choice holds?

Comment: @BrianO Yes. And you are checking the range of  $|\cdot|$ applied to $\Omega$, isn't it? :-)

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf (Not sure what you're asking there.) Even if members of $\Omega$ aren't ordinals, each is bijectable with a (von Neumann) ordinal, and if $\Omega$ is a set then by Replacement so is the "set" of all corresponding vN ordinals, and the union of *that* is $\mathsf{Ord}$.

Comment: @BrianO I was asking exactly what you are answering now. And actually the map you are using when applying Replacement is “taking cardinals”, $X\mapsto |X|$. I asked my first question because without your last explanation, your first comment might have confused the OP.